# update nuget package on pre-build (prompt for modified files)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a modular web-application written in asp.net mvc5 and within my main-application i want to update all modules (nuget-packages) from my local package-source (local folder).
I archieve this by putting the following line as pre-build event for my main-application (the packages themself are generated on post-build event of the module-projects).

```
nuget update packages.config -Source $(SolutionDir)ModulePackageSource\
```

My problem is, that when i do this in my visual-studio pre-build event instead of the package-manager console, i dont get prompted if i want to replace modified files (which i really want to - otherwise it just ignores those files and i may end up with an inconsistent application).
Is there a way to still get the prompt when using the VisualStudio build-events?

Comment: Must you use VS build events? What about a build script instead?

Comment: @Matthew Skelton: Could you ellaborate about that? Is that also for local builds or only for things like team-city?

Comment: The advantage of using (say) `build.cmd`, `rebuild.cmd`, etc. with a build tool like *psake* is that you can use the essentially same build script on a developer box as on the CI server. You can target specific portions of the solution by passing in build targets e.g. `build web` or `rebuild lib`. It's slightly less integrated with VS but ends up being *much* more flexible/powerful and your build configuration is declarative rather than 'hidden' in VS.